# Firebase Android

Tags: android, arraylist, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

after taking data with takeModel in OnDataChange() I want to put them into arraylist, which is resposinble for creating activity.

```
 final String[] takeModel = null;
            ....
    myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            int i=0;
            int lenght = (int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
            String[] takeModel = new String[lenght];
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                TvAtributes tvnowe = postSnapshot.getValue(TvAtributes.class);

                takeModel[i]=tvnowe.getModel(); // taking data here   
                i++;
            }

        }
        ......
      ArrayList<TvAtributes> tv_models = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0;i<android_version_names.length;i++){
        TvAtributes tvModele = new TvAtributes();
        tvModele.setModel(takeModel[i]);  //this is crashing 
        tvModele.setImgaddres(image_urls[i]);
        tv_models.add(tvModele);
```

I have no clue what to do.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to understand the concept of asynchronous calls and mutltithreading...

Comment: Also you should learn some java's basics like variable's scopes...

Comment: The problem is that the ArrayList tv_models is waiting for 2 arrays, one of them Im definig in the begging as private final, the second i want to take from the db

Answer (score 0):

The answer is

```
final ArrayList<TvAtributes> tv_models = new ArrayList<>();
 .....
  @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            int i=0;
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                TvAtributes tvnowe = postSnapshot.getValue(TvAtributes.class);
                tvnowe.getModel();
                tvnowe.setImgaddres(image_urls[i]);
                tv_models.add(tvnowe);
                i++;
            }
            ...
           return tv_models;
```

Thanks for help